# JMESPath nested OR statement

Tags: python, json, map-function, jmespath

I am using [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org) in Python to efficiently parse large dictionaries/lists.

I have a list of dictionaries, for each dictionary I would like to obtain a certain value or return `null` and put the result into a list. i.e. im selecting a field from each dictionary but including a null value where the field dosn't exist.

For example, my input is:

```
[
    {
        'foo': {'bar': 'yes1'}
    },
    {
        'foo': {'bar': 'yes2'}
    },
    {
        'foo1': {'bar': 'no'}
    }
]
```

The result I want is:

```
['yes1', 'yes2', None]
```

So for each dictionary in the list I want the path `foo.bar` or I want to return `None` if the path dosn't exist. The pseudo JMESPath expression I want is:

```
[*]( foo.bar||`null` )
```

i.e. select all list, then try the path foo.bar or return the literal null. **However the brackets are syntactically incorrect. How do I encapsulate an OR expression in brackets?** The best JMESPath expression I got is:

```
[*][foo.bar||``][]
```

The first two terms ``` [*][foo.bar||``] ``` places each element into a list nested into a list `[['yes1'], ['yes2'], ['']]`, then the `[]` flattens the returned list. However this is quite convulted and prevents me returning a null, so instead I return an empty string.

Does any one have any ideas? Am I missing something syntactically?

Comment: This not currently supported, but I've proposed a map() function to be added to the language that will do this: https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.site/issues/15

Answer (score 2):

Since JMESPATH 0.9 a [`map` function](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#map) has been added. So now you can use the below expression to get the desired result:

```
map(&foo.bar, [*])
```